# Red or Blue clases Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am android studio noob, sorry for the question but, why are these classes red or blue? What does it mean?

[image]

Comment: remove .git folder from your project root directory       -BLUE- file is pending commit color on git and -RED- color is pending to upload new file on git

Comment: @milanpithadia you can't just delete the .git folder if you actually want to use git

Comment: git is website to save your code in git server and you can access any time using login and download your code

Comment: @milanpithadia That's not how it works. The .git folder needs to stay there if you want to *actually* use git as it was intended to track file changes.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you're using git.

red files are new files, not tracked by git,

blue files are tracked by git, but have changes you haven't committed

---

extra info
[image]

android studio also applies this *inside* files, the green on the left here indicates that I've made a change to this file, you can actually click on it to review what has changed. Green for new content, blue for any previous code which has been committed and has now been changed and it will show `>` for anything which is now deleted